# phpmyadmin saying it shows paginated results, but is in fact showing all

Tags: phpmyadmin

Are there any aspects of a sql query statement which could cause phpmyadmin to show this kind of behavior? Usually, when a query returns more record than what's configured as the page size, then the results are paginated.

But I have a query for which on the results page it says: "Showing rows 0 - 24 (24270 total, Query took 0.5729 seconds.)", but I can see on the page that it clearly shows all records. The page/browser became super slow as it had to render a massive table, it took minutes until the results appeared (although it said the query took just 0.5729 seconds). But I managed to copy the result table to the clipboard and to paste it into Excel, and I got 24271 rows (including the header).

When clicking on the double arrow to go to the last page, it again takes very long until the page loads, and the it says in the header: "Showing rows 24270 - 24270 (24270 total, Query took 0.5729 seconds.)". The results table has again 24270 rows.

I could use a LIMIT to limit the results on screen and hence speed up rendering the results table, but I need export all results, and I assume it would only export the LIMITed number of results.

I am using a GROUP BY clause, several JOINs, GROUP_CONCAT. But I did that before and I never saw this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it was the usage of the reserved word 'Status' as a JOIN alias, without using backticks.